# The Keyword then is missing Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting an error The Keyword then is missing in my code, I cannot find why it is giving me the error. The error cursor is after the "Various"  Any ideas

`IF (isnull({148_vwWorksOrderReportFeed.Expr6})) OR IF (isnull ({WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomer})) OR IF (({WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomerVarious})) = False Then "Stock"  Else IF  not isnull({148_vwWorksOrderReportFeed.Expr6})  THEN    {148_vwWorksOrderReportFeed.Expr6}  Else IF not isNull({WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomer}) THEN {WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomer} Else If {WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomerVarious} = True THEN "Various"`

I have tried various syntax and googled the life out of it but cannot find anything to explain why it is happening, could be my lack of knowledge in stsntax of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

IF (isnull({148_vwWorksOrderReportFeed.Expr6})) OR (isnull ({WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomer})) OR ({WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomerVarious} = False) Then "Stock"  Else IF not isnull({148_vwWorksOrderReportFeed.Expr6})  THEN {148_vwWorksOrderReportFeed.Expr6}  Else IF not isNull({WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomer}) THEN {WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomer} Else If {WorksOrderHeader.udfCustomerVarious} = True THEN "Various"